# Well formed formulas of all mathematical proof

Tags: logic, set-theory, computational-complexity

Last week, I asked the "automated proof-checking machine."  Many answered that automated proof-checking machine already exists in first-order theory.

However I have still question. For the operation of 'automated proof-checking machine', the input (mathematical proof) must be transformed into 'well formed formula'.

I found an article which insists that well formed formula include all theorem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language

Is it possible that all proof (maybe in ZFC) can be transform as formal language (well-formed formula) ?

Comment: Um, no, "$(\Leftrightarrow\wedge\neg\vee\exists\forall\supset\rightarrow)$" is not even close to being a well-formed formula. It's just bunch of random symbols that are _not_ put together according to the syntax rules that define what a well-formed formula is.

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm. Surealy, (⇔∧¬∨∃∀⊃→) is not well-formed formula. I just want to show an example of the formular. I should have written as "combination of (⇔,∧,¬,∨,∃,∀,⊃,→,......). My question is, as you said, whether all proof can be transformed as "symbols that are put together according to the syntax rules that define what a well-formed formula is". – HoCheol SHIN 14 mins ago

Comment: Not all combinations of those symbols are well-formed formulas.  Only a subset of those combinations which follow certain rules are wffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the set of formal proofs is a formal language in itself. It is not the same as the formal language of formulas, though. For example, we might define a proof to be a certain kind of *finite sequence* of formulas, or we might define a proof to be a certain kind of labeled finite tree.